# How to prevent entering same character twice (one after another) in HTML textbox using plain JavaScript (not using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

a) If I want to type word 'call' second letter 'l' in word 'call' has to be prevented from entering.

b) If I want to type '54662', after '5', '4', '6' are typed (appeared), second '6' has to be prevented from appearing in the text while I'm pressing key '6'.

c) It is ok with word 'olala'. It should not be prevented from entering.

Thanks for any feedback in advance.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You also forgot to include a [mcve]  of what you tried (Unless you think that this website is a code writing service, which it isn't)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an onChange event on your input which should be calling a function and passing e (event object) as parameter.

Then use string length to check if the newest character equals a character before it, if so, prevent default else continue.

```
var lastChar = myString[myString.length-1];
var prevChar = myString[myString.length-2];

 If (lastChar == prevChar){
     e.preventDefault();
 }
```

Comment: It works only at the end of text (when 'Enter' pressed). It doesn't check character by character as required. Am I right?

Comment: Try using onblur, which will work for every keystroke

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id = "inp">
</body>
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById('inp');
    input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        if (input.value[input.value.length - 1] === input.value[input.value.length - 2]){
            input.value = input.value.slice(0,-1);
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work when key is held pressed (continiously).

Comment: Try using multiple events, seperated by comma. Like paste keydown change blur

Answer (score 0):

Before allowing any character entered, check the current value last char if the new char entered is different allow it otherwise return.

I'm not adding any code since you didn't add any code of your own and the question itself is kinda vague

a few guides to help you getting started,
[How to fetch dom elements using pure JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)
[get input value from dom input field](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't actually ask a question, I'll give some pointers instead of a copy/paste answer

What you want to achieve is done by listening to events, in this case the `keydown` event on a form input

- In general you'd register your event listener to a DOM-element using the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method of it
- Any DOM element can be found using the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) methods
- In order to see what value is already entered when the event triggers, you can use `this.value` (as the event target is set to the DOM-element, which is then the input element, if you're using ES5 style function notation)
- The last character of the input-element can be obtained using the last character position on the string value (`string[string.length - 1]`)
- The event (`keydown`) can be prevented (`event.preventDefault()`) if you don't want to allow the resulting character, resulting in the character not being added

As for the tricky part, you should consider the input being pasted or the cursor not being at the end of the input.

You'll figure out there's the `input` event on input-elements and you'll end up diving deep into smart ways to determine whether there are consecutive equal characters and `filter` them.